# Radio buttons looses values when scrolling in RecyclerView

Tags: android, xamarin, android-recyclerview, android-viewholder, android-radiogroup

Please help me spot the bug! I have read numerous posts here on this issue but I can't get mine to work. To me it looks like I'm doing it according to the other solutions but I'm missing something.

I have a survey implemented as a question with 3 possible answers using recyclerview where each row has a radio group with 3 radio buttons.

When scrolling the radio button looses its value and doesn't get set again in the onbind event.

```
public class MyQItem
{
    public int Id;
    public string Question;
    public int Value;

    public MyQItem(int id, string question)
    {
        Id = id;
        Question = question;
    }
}

internal class MyQFormAdapter : RecyclerView.Adapter
{
    private MyQItem[] mDataSource;

    public MyQFormAdapter(MyQItem[] mDataSource)
    {
        this.mDataSource = mDataSource;
    }

    public override int ItemCount => mDataSource.Length;

    public override void OnBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position)
    {
        MyQViewHolder vh = holder as MyQViewHolder;

        vh.QuestionId.Text = mDataSource[position].Id.ToString();
        vh.Question.Text = mDataSource[position].Question;

        vh.Button1.CheckedChange -= Button1_CheckedChange;
        vh.Button2.CheckedChange -= Button2_CheckedChange;
        vh.Button3.CheckedChange -= Button3_CheckedChange;

        vh.Button1.Checked = mDataSource[position].Value == 1;
        vh.Button2.Checked = mDataSource[position].Value == 2;
        vh.Button3.Checked = mDataSource[position].Value == 3;

        vh.Button1.Tag = position;
        vh.Button2.Tag = position;
        vh.Button3.Tag = position;

        vh.Button1.CheckedChange += Button1_CheckedChange;
        vh.Button2.CheckedChange += Button2_CheckedChange;
        vh.Button3.CheckedChange += Button3_CheckedChange;
    }

    void Button1_CheckedChange(object sender, CompoundButton.CheckedChangeEventArgs e) => SetChecked((RadioButton)sender, 1, e.IsChecked);
    void Button2_CheckedChange(object sender, CompoundButton.CheckedChangeEventArgs e) => SetChecked((RadioButton)sender, 2, e.IsChecked);
    void Button3_CheckedChange(object sender, CompoundButton.CheckedChangeEventArgs e) => SetChecked((RadioButton)sender, 3, e.IsChecked);

    void SetChecked(RadioButton btn, int value, bool isChecked)
    {
        if (!isChecked)
            return;

        var position = (int)btn.Tag;
        mDataSource[position].Value = value;
    }

    public override RecyclerView.ViewHolder OnCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType)
    {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.From(parent.Context).Inflate(Resource.Layout.MyQItemLayout, parent, false);

        MyQViewHolder vh = new MyQViewHolder(itemView);
        return vh;
    }
}

[Activity(Label = "MyQEditActivity")]
public class MyQEditActivity : Activity
{
    MyQItem[] mDataSource = new MyQItem[] { 
        new MyQItem(1, "Lorem Ipsum"),
        new MyQItem(2, "Lorem Ipsum"),
        new MyQItem(3, "Lorem Ipsum"),
        new MyQItem(4, "Lorem Ipsum"),
        new MyQItem(5, "Lorem Ipsum"),
        new MyQItem(6, "Lorem Ipsum"),
        new MyQItem(7, "Lorem Ipsum"),
        new MyQItem(8, "Lorem Ipsum"),
        new MyQItem(9, "Lorem Ipsum"),
        new MyQItem(10, "Lorem Ipsum"),
        new MyQItem(11, "Lorem Ipsum"),
        new MyQItem(12, "Lorem Ipsum"),
    };

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.MyQEditLayout);

        var recyclerView = FindViewById<RecyclerView>(Resource.Id.recyclerView);
        recyclerView.SetLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        recyclerView.SetAdapter(new MyQFormAdapter(mDataSource));
    }

}

public class MyQViewHolder : RecyclerView.ViewHolder
{
    public TextView QuestionId { get; private set; }
    public TextView Question { get; private set; }
    public RadioButton Button1 { get; private set; }
    public RadioButton Button2 { get; private set; }
    public RadioButton Button3 { get; private set; }

    public MyQViewHolder(View itemView) : base(itemView)
    {
        QuestionId = itemView.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.MyQuestionId);
        Question = itemView.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.MyQuestion);

        Button1 = itemView.FindViewById<RadioButton>(Resource.Id.noButton);
        Button2 = itemView.FindViewById<RadioButton>(Resource.Id.someButton);
        Button3 = itemView.FindViewById<RadioButton>(Resource.Id.yesButton);
    }
}
```

Comment: Code looks fine.... So you are saying the radio button(s) are not being set but the text of `QuestionId` and `Question` are begin set in the `OnBindViewHolder`?

Comment: The text are set fine and the list displays correctly on loading. When I check the first radio button and then scroll so the onbind event fires to spawn the new rows and I them scroll back again the radio button is cleared even though i can follow the position been set (checked) again while debugging. Also the radio button cannot be "checked again" in the ui? Only by clicking Button2 or Button3 first, allows me to select Button1 again?! So it kind of feels like the button is checked but the UI doesn't show it?! The button "reacts" in the UI with the orange click color but the "dot" isn't set.

Comment: Seems like a UI refresh/display issue, not a problem in the code shown. What API level are you testing on?, emulator or device? Have you tried a different device?

Comment: FYI: I c/p your code into a blank project and added two layouts and your code is fine...

Comment: vh.Button1.CheckedChange += Button1_CheckedChange; in OnBindViewHolder can be problematic, as they will stackup for every time an item becomes visible

Comment: @SushiHangover I'm running it on a device with target 28 and device on the same.

Comment: @JoachimHaglund Thanks! You're probably right even tough I don't quite get it, as I find that it usually works to remove the wiring first to avoid multiple events?! Anyways, the below reply from Leo Zhu works for me and is what I'll use!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add listeners to your **RadioGroup** and modify your adapter like this：

```
class MyQFormAdapter : RecyclerView.Adapter, RadioGroup.IOnCheckedChangeListener
{
    private MyQItem[] mDataSource;
    public MyQFormAdapter(MyQItem[] mDataSource)
     {
      this.mDataSource = mDataSource;
     }


    public override int ItemCount => mDataSource.Length;

    public override void OnBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position)
    {
        MyQViewHolder vh = holder as MyQViewHolder;

       // cancel the listener to prevent RadioGroup from displaying confusing key codes
        vh.Group.SetOnCheckedChangeListener(null);
        vh.Group.ClearCheck();
        vh.Group.Tag = position;

        switch (mDataSource[position].Value)
        {
            case 1:
                vh.Group.Check(Resource.Id.noButton);
                break;
            case 2:
                vh.Group.Check(Resource.Id.someButton);
                break;
            case 3:
                vh.Group.Check(Resource.Id.yesButton);
                break;

        }
        vh.QuestionId.Text = mDataSource[position].Id.ToString();
        vh.Question.Text = mDataSource[position].Question;
        vh.Group.SetOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
    }
    public override RecyclerView.ViewHolder OnCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType)
    {

        View itemView = LayoutInflater.From(parent.Context).Inflate(Resource.Layout.MyQItemLayout, parent,false);

        MyQViewHolder vh = new MyQViewHolder(itemView);
        return vh;
    }

    public class MyQViewHolder : RecyclerView.ViewHolder
    {
        public TextView QuestionId { get; private set; }
        public TextView Question { get; private set; }

        public RadioGroup Group { get; private set; }
        public MyQViewHolder(View itemView) : base(itemView)
        {
            QuestionId = itemView.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.MyQuestionId);
            Question = itemView.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.MyQuestion);
            Group = itemView.FindViewById<RadioGroup>(Resource.Id.radiogroup);
        }
    }

    public void OnCheckedChanged(RadioGroup @group, int checkedId)
    {
        switch (checkedId)
        {
            case Resource.Id.noButton:
                mDataSource[(int) @group.Tag].Value = 1;
                break;
            case Resource.Id.someButton:
                mDataSource[(int)@group.Tag].Value = 2;
                break;
            case Resource.Id.yesButton:
                mDataSource[(int)@group.Tag].Value = 3;
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This solution works for me, looks cleaner and is what I will use but I'm not clear on what's wrong in the initial post? Is it as @Joachim Haglund suggets that is has to do with the wiring of the CheckedChanged event?